# how to get geotiff image

Tags: r

I want to have a Geotiff image in R.How can I do that? Following is a simple example. I want to have the produced plot in Geotiff format.

```
require(gstat)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
data(meuse.grid)
gridded(meuse.grid) = ~x+y
m <- vgm(.59, "Sph", 874, .04)
# ordinary kriging:
x <- krige(log(zinc)~1, meuse, meuse.grid, model = m)
spplot(x["var1.pred"], main = "ordinary kriging predictions")
```

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense. A Geotiff is a raster, your points are vector data. What are you planning to do with the Geotiff when you have it?

Comment: I edited the code. what I want at last is a  prediction map.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert your SpatialPixelsDataFrame to a raster and write it:

```
> require(raster)
> r = raster(x["var1.pred"])
> plot(r)
> writeRaster(r,"r.tiff","GTiff")
```

The `plot` is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Write the SpatialPixelsDataFrame directly to a raster format using [`rgdal`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html), which provides bindings to [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/). There are many things you can do with GDAL, such as reading and/or writing a wide range of raster formats, pixel types, do coordinate transformations, support multiple bands, etc.

```
require(rgdal)
writeGDAL(x["var1.pred"], "var1_pred.tif")
```